# Display error login message on custom spring boot login form

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm working on a custom spring boot login form. When user provides wrong credentials, I want my application redirect to the same page and show an error. What I tried, is to create my own `failureHandler` and there in `onAuthenticationFailure` pass a parameter to a request. Then in my login .jsp form check if this parameter exists and based on it show an error, but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf()
            .disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**")
                .hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/user/**")
                .hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/guest*")
                .permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/guest/login")
            .permitAll()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/user/all-tasks", true)
            .failureUrl("/guest/login")
            .failureHandler(new MyAuthenticationFailureHandler())
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/user/logout")
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");
}
```

```
@Component
public class MyAuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
        request.setAttribute("error", true);
    }
}
```

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/guest")
public class GuestController {
    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login(){
        return "login";
    }
}
```

```
<div>
    <c:if test="${error == true}">
        <h1>DUPA</h1>
    </c:if>
</div>
```

Comment: Show your controller code responsible for login action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When login fails. Spring security sends you back on the same login page with special request param something like `guest/login?error` or You can change this to custom by setting up `.failureUrl()` in security config which you are not doing.

So change it to `.failureUrl("/guest/login?error")`

Use this `error` param to identify if something went wrong using `${not empty param.error}` .

I am guessing you are using JSP and the `EL` is by default available. 
You can add something like below on your login page which will give you the actual reason why it failed.

```
<c:if test="${not empty param.error}">
            <p style="color:red">
                Your login attempt was not
                successful, try again.<br /> Reason: <c:out
                    value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}" />.
            </p>
        </c:if>
```

Where `SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION` param is available in user's session scope added by spring security with actual cause.

Comment: I should say thank you, but this is the solution I already knew :/ I try to make a login error message with no changing URL. Sorry for not mentioning that in question.

Comment: then use `request.getSession().setAttribute("error", true)` in your `MyAuthenticationFailureHandler` Rest would work what you have in place.