# How can I hide a div when the message string is empty? (specifically: SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, spring-security

I have a web app built with Bootstrap 3 and Java / Spring MVC.

I'm building a custom login form page for Spring Security.

Works fine except this part where the error message box is always displayed even when the error message is empty string ...

```
<c:if test="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message ne ''}">
    <div id="dangerAlert" class="alert alert-danger" >
        ${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}
    </div>
</c:if>
```

How can I check if this string `${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}` is empty and hide the div?

Comment: Here is the solution:. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62163429/display-error-login-message-on-custom-spring-boot-login-form/62203695?noredirect=1#comment110014245_62203695

Comment: Thanks for the help, I read through that answer, but it seems excessive to change the config to pass around an 'error' param like the answer says.  Isn't there a simple way for me to check if "SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message" is an empty string, or check the string length and act on that?

Comment: Also -- I just tried this and still didn't work ... not sure what I'm missing ... `<c:if test="${not empty SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}">`

Comment: @Rajeev I figured it out ... I am a moron ... I was not importing the  "c" taglib at the top of the new file `login.jsp`.  I'll update with a solution momentarily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question (and thanks to @Rajeev for pointing me a good direction that helped).

This works ...

```
<c:if test="${not empty SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}">
    <div id="dangerAlert" class="alert alert-danger" >
        ${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}
    </div>
</c:if>
```

NOTE: Don't forget to import the correct tag lib in your JSP like I did  forgot to do ...

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```